# running git on a linux server vs github

Tags: git, github

I'm considering using git for source code management. I'm a little confused as to whether I should setup a ubuntu server with git or just use github ? Is there really any advantage of using github ? Also, how would you deploy the code from git (or github) to the production server if the production server does not have git installed ? Do I have to write some kind of deployment script in php (using ftp functions) or use shell script ?

Thanks

Comment: one advantage is that in case your server goes up in flames, your code on github will still be there. BTW - this is not a either-or thing. You can have both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Git doesn't need a server to operate at all.
You can install it on your local machine, create a repository and start using it.

A remote git installation (which you can do on your own remote server or which github.com provides for free) is only needed to create a remote copy of your git repository (useful if you're going to be programming from multiple locations, or if you want to share your source code's history with the world)

The advantage of github - public repos are free, it has GUI clients for Windows and Mac (don't know about Linux).

Deploying the code to a production server is a completely different thing - it has nothing to do with git. There's no need for git to be installed on the production server.

Comment: +1 beside tools like `gitk` there is at least one full-fledged git UI for linux (and other platforms) - SmartGit

Comment: What is a good way for deplyoing the code then ? Would it make sense to write a script that takes the latest version from the development server and FTP uploads it to the remote server (after deleting the existing contents) ?

Comment: Yes, that is the preferred way. (AFAIK)

Comment: But wouldn't it be slow if there are a lot of files on the server ?